# Why is an H bridge needed in a bidirectional motor control circuit?

Tags: dc-motor

I'm trying to understand figure IV in this [article about controlling motors](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/DC-Motors-2), and I do not see why the H bridge is needed. As best as I can tell, this is so that if the motor is stopped (by making the two inputs equal) then the back EMF can be snubbed and avoid damage to the IC. Is this right?

If so, I do not understand the comment that says the diodes must be able to pass the full current of the motor, because it seems they would only be used when the motor is stopped, which would produce only a transient current through the H bridge, and not pass current while the motor is being run.

Would another way of avoiding such damage be to slowly wind the motor down by reducing the PWM duty cycle on the enable line?

Would another way be to turn off the enable line? I guess in that case, you get coasting stop (which might not be what you want)?

Comment: Assuming the buffer outputs vary between +VE and ground as shown on that circuit, you're correct: the diodes are never forward biased except by any transient back EMF generated by the motor. Possibly you and/or the author are confused about what an 'H bridge' actually is - in that circuit the 'H' is made by the output devices in the two buffers.

Comment: IMHO that's a terrible article, there are bits that are just wrong (like Figure III), and the IC he references is 20 years old and not even available any more fro either Digi-Key or Mouser.

Answer (score 1):

> If so, I do not understand the comment that says the diodes must be
>   able to pass the full current of the motor, because it seems they
>   would only be used when the motor is stopped, which would produce only
>   a transient current through the H bridge, and not pass current while
>   the motor is being run.

The H bridge supplies the motor with current and the instant that one side of the H bridge is controlled to go open circuit, the same motor current will still flow and that current will cause a large back-emf if there isn't a low impedance path for it to naturally decay to zero.

The diodes therefore have to be able handle full load motor current for that brief period of time when the current has to decay to zero. For PWM control this is quite often every cycle of PWM. For plain ordinary on/off control, the current is only going to flow through the diodes when the motor is turned off.

In summary, current doesn't instantly become a lower value when the motor is open circuited.

Comment: But that inductive kickback is caused by the motor series inductance (a non ideal property), not the motor back EMF (angular velocity induced voltage).

Comment: @jms Can you elaborate? I am talking about the inductive kick-back in my answer BTW.

Comment: I know. I meant that a theoretical, ideal DC motor would have zero inductance (so no inductive kickback at all), resistance or capacitance but would still have an induced voltage caused by the motor acting as a generator when spinning (back EMF). The back EMF is what defines the RPM of an unloaded motor at any given voltage, since when the supply voltage and back EMF of a motor are equal no current can flow.

Comment: @jms Yes I'm aware of that but how does it relate to the current rating on the diodes - are you making a point about that?

Comment: The diodes will be subject to the full current trough the motor. I was making a point on the distinction of back EMF and inductive kickback: the diode isn't there to counter the effects of back EMF, but the effects of inductive kickback. Now that I read it again I noticed that you do not disagree on your answer so I don't even know why I commented in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a full H-bridge to control a motor, but you do need the diodes to prevent enormous voltages from inductive kicks as the commutator disconnects the motor voltage from each coil in the winding.

Where you DO need the full bridge is when you want to *reverse* the motor with a single supply (say, +12v instead of separate +/-12V supplies).